# Can a package final variable be changed through reflection?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Can a package final variable be changed through reflection?

Say I have this:

```
public class Widget {
  final int val = 23;
}
```

Can the val be changed through reflection if made accessible?

If so, is there any way to prevent it that without using the security manager?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection helps you

Comment: If so, is there any way to prevent it that without using the security manager?

Comment: Is it a requirement or you are just experimentin

Comment: Must be made so as to ensure runtime inlineable code, so a requirement.

Comment: try the one i have mentioned below

Comment: so, even a final class can have a private final value changed???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, changing final members causes reflection-obtained values to differ from values returned by regular code! This is quite scary.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

    private static final class Widget {
        private final int val = 23;

        public int getVal() {
            return val;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Widget w = new Widget ();

        Field m = Widget.class.getDeclaredField("val");

        m.setAccessible(true);

        m.set(w, 233);

        Field m1 = Widget.class.getDeclaredField("val");
        m1.setAccessible(true);


        System.out.println(m.get(w)); /// PRINT 233
        System.out.println(w.getVal()); /// PRINT 23
        System.out.println(m1.get(w)); /// PRINT 233

    }
}
```

Comment: This is very weird! We need to investigate more

Comment: `final int val = 23;` defines compile-time constant. Every access to it gets replaced by the constant value at compile-time already. Compile-time constants don’t need to be `static`, though it is useless to reserve space in every object instance of `Widget` for a field that is never read at runtime (besides when using Reflection).

Answer (score 4):

YES. Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Widget w = new Widget ();

    Field m = Widget.class.getDeclaredField("val");

    m.setAccessible(true);

    m.set(w, 233);

    System.out.println(m.get(w)); /// PRINT 233
}
```

Comment: But `System.out.println(w.val);` shows `23`, not `233`. So unless you're doing the access through reflection...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder cool. OK, so how does that work? Why the field but not using the getter?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: You are right! Developers need to be aware of this!

Comment: @SaintHill: My guess would be that because the member is `final`, the compiler or JIT was able to inline the value as it's effectively a constant (barring people mucking about with it via reflection :-) ). I don't know the details.

Comment: It is. If you make the final field something that doesn't become a compile time constant (something non-string non-primitive), it will show up in the actual object.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 Widget() {
     checkPerMission();
  }
     private void checkPerMission() {
         Class self = sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(1);
          Class caller = sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(3);
         if (self != caller) {
             throw new java.lang.IllegalAccessError();
         }

 }
```

Comment: please add comment before making it negative